# Card header Stop propagation not working,

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm using a card header to open the card body, and inside the header I have a button (add button).
The problem is that when I click the (add button) the card body get opened and the expected behevior is to execute only the button code. Below my code

```
<div class="card recoCard">
 <div class="card-header recoHeader" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
  data-bs-target="#recouvrementCard" aria-expanded="false"
  aria-controls="recouvrementCard">
   <span> Some placeholder content for the collapse component. </span>
    <span>
     <button class="btn btn-success addButton" type="button" (click)="addToList()">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
     </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse" id="recouvrementCard">
   <div class="card card-body recoCardBody">
    Some placeholder content for the collapse component. This panel is hidden by
    default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is that events in JavaScript [bubble](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing), which means that

> When an event happens on an element, it first runs the handlers on it, then on its parent, then all the way up on other ancestors

It's pretty simple to stop event bubbling in this case with `$event.stopPropagation()`:

```html
<button class="btn btn-success addButton" type="button" (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); addToList()">
```

Comment: I have added this code to the button and it works ```data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target```